# Background image will not show on mobile (iPhone 6s)

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am currently working on a website and everything works and functions fine except the background image on mobile. I have quite literally tried everything and it will not show on mobile even though it shows just fine on my laptop. The phone I have is an iPhone 6s and it just doesn't want to show. I have used the same CSS code in other projects and it works just fine but it won't currently.

I have done some testing and the issue seems to be the background-position: cover. But what is a way around this without making the image look bad. Also when I click the mobile nav button to open the menu... you can see the image show in the back which is extremely strange...

Does anybody have any possible solutions to this? It's extremely frustrating.

Here is the link to the site: http://mujomusic.net/WDV351/Konstrukt/index.php

and the code:

```
height: 100vh;
background-image: url('images/main.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Hi, some times you need [meta for mobile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for active css for mobile. I don't know if this is the situation. This is the [page that explane this of W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid advice, but did you try to clear the cache?

Comment: I already have a viewport set... so that isn't the issue...

Comment: I tried clearing it and nothing ... ugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would u give a screenshot ,because it is working perfectly fine on mine.
Could be cache Issue.
[image]

Comment: Check it please.

Comment: I just checked after clearing my cache once more and it showed up... WOW.

Comment: Try using incognito mode everytime you want to check ,it helps a lot. thanks :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks so much for your help!